# How to update binding dynamically when source object changes?

Tags: wpf, binding

**What I have?**

I have `Frame` in XAML, (binding works properly).

```
<Frame Name="frmMainContent"
             DataContext="MyPageInformation"
             Source="{Binding ElementName=thisPage, Path=MyPageInformation.UserControlPath}"
             NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"></Frame>
```

In the code behind I have a `DependencyProperty` of my class, `PageInformation`

```
public static DependencyProperty PageInformationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyPageInformation", typeof(PageInformation), typeof(Administration));

    public PageInformation MyPageInformation
    {
        get { retur n (PageInformation)GetValue(PageInformationProperty); }
        set{ SetValue(PageInformationProperty, value); }
    }
```

**What I want?**

The `Frame` should update its binding whenever value of `MyPageInformation` changes.

Can somebody tell me how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to be mode clear with you question. There are discrepancies between the XAML and C# code.

Comment: Discrepancies corrected. Thanks!

Comment: hey, why no up-vote? you didn't like the "answer"? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make the PageInformationProperty a dependency property just for this binding. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the code behind.

Also since you are actually binding to "UserControlPath", make sure that this property actually sends change notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing I'll tell you is that all binding errors appear on the Output window. So you need to look at it and find out if you have any errors.

The next thing.. for bindings to update automatically, you either need to make the property it is "binded" to, either a dependency property, or implement INotifyPropertyChanged for other classes.

Be sure that the property that you exactly bind to, is either one of these cases.